# Vuetify sizing not working

Tags: vuetify.js

I have been trying to make the selects half the size of the card width instead of the full width. I have been using `<v-flex xs-6>` but it does not seem to work. Why does this not work?

```
 <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height text-xs-center>
        <v-layout align-center justify-center>
          <v-flex xs6>
            <v-card class="elevation-12">
                <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                    <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-card-text>
                    <v-form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <h4 align="left">Have you ever been arrested for driving under the influence of alcohol?</h4>
                        <v-radio-group v-model="q21" row>
                            <v-radio
                                label="False"
                                value="false"
                                color="red"
                            ></v-radio>
                            <v-radio
                                label="True"
                                value="true"
                                color="green"
                            ></v-radio>
                        </v-radio-group>
                        <v-flex xs-6>
                        <v-select
                            v-if="q21 == 'true'"
                            :items="items"
                            v-model="q21Yes"
                            label="How many times?"
                            class="input-group--focused"
                            item-value="text"
                        ></v-select>
                        </v-flex>
                        <h4 align="left">Have you ever been arrested, even for a few hours because of other behavior while drinking?</h4>
                        <v-radio-group v-model="q22" row>
                            <v-radio
                                label="False"
                                value="false"
                                color="red"
                            ></v-radio>
                            <v-radio
                                label="True"
                                value="true"
                                color="green"
                            ></v-radio>
                        </v-radio-group>
                        <v-flex xs-6>
                        <v-select
                            v-if="q22 == 'true'"
                            :items="items"
                            v-model="q22Yes"
                            label="How many times?"
                            class="input-group--focused"
                            item-value="text"
                        ></v-select>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-flex>
                        <v-btn @click="save()" color="primary">Submit</v-btn>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
```

Comment: Can you clarify, what does it mean "doesn't work"? which part? I see you have a typo in `xs-6`, it should be `xs6`.

Comment: And if it not come from the ypo, please post a CodePen reproducing the issue you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Traxo's answer was correct, I was used to doing xs-6 when it should have been xs6.